# facts in prolog that I have checked before

Tags: prolog, logic, inference

I have this knowledge base in prolog...

```
start :- navabi(C).
male(X,N) :-
   write('Is this a male? '), flush_output,
   read(yes).

navabi(N):- male(N) -> print('he is navabi') ; mirian(N).
mirian(N):- not( male(N)), print('she is ms.mirian').
female(X) :- not(male(X)).
```

The problem is that when I start this program and enter someone who is not a male, the program goes to mirian. and then I print another one, and it again goes to see if that person is male ( however it shout be aware that this 'N' is not a male ) but it again asks 'Is this a male?'.
It seems that prolog forgets about the previous knowledge. Can any one help me with this?

regards.

Comment: please give the rest of your program and precise what exactly you enter and what exactly is the result. Atm the program does not compile (`male/1` is not defined) and the process you use to enter who is a male and who is not and to keep track of that is totally unclear.

Answer (score 1):

you call male/1 while (in the code you posted) there is only male/2. this usually leads to an exception unless male/1 is declared as dynamic; then, male(N) will always be false. I guess that in some prolog variations it could always be considered false even if it's static; what prolog version are you using?

to assert new data use [asserta/1 or assertz/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.12%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/db.html%27%29%29); prolog does not have memory as you noticed!